# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 9c: Understanding comment at end of problem item.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

> 9. (a) Problem $7(i)$ amounts to the equation
>
> $$P_{n,a,f+g}=P_{n,a,f}+P_{n,a,g}$$
>
> Give a more direct proof by writing
>
> $$f(x)=P_{n,a,f}(x)+R_{n,a,f}(x)\tag{1}$$
>
> $$g(x)=P_{n,a,g}(x)+R_{n,a,g}(x)\tag{2}$$
>
> and using the obvious fact about $R_{n,a,f}+R_{n,a,g}$.
>
> (b) Similarly, Problem $7(ii)$ could be used to show that
>
> $$P_{n,a,fg}=[P_{n,a,f}\cdot P_{n,a,g}]_n$$
>
> where $[P]_n$ denotes the truncation of $P$ to degree $n$, the sum of
> all terms of $P$ of degree $\leq n$ [with $P$ written as a polynomial
> in $x-a$]. Again, give a more direct proof, using the obvious facts
> about products involving terms of the form $R_n$.
>
> (c) Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in $x-a$ and
> $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$ then
>
> $$p(q(x)+R(x))=p(q(x))+\bar{R}(x)$$
>
> where $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\bar{R}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$$
>
> Also note that if $p$ is a polynomial in $x-a$ having only terms of
> degree $>n$, and $q$ is a polynomial in $x-a$ whose constant term is
> $> 0$, then all terms of $p(q(x-a))$ are of degree $>n$.

My question regards the comment at the end of item $(c)$.

Let $p$ and $q$ be polynomials in $x-a$ such that terms in $p$ have degree $>n$, and the constant term in $q$ is $0$.

$$p(x)=\sum\limits_{i=n}^{m_1} a_i (x-a)^i$$

$$q(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m_2} b_i (x-a)^i$$

What is $q(x-a)$?

Is it

$$q(x-a)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m_2} b_i (x-2a)^i$$

Or is it just

$$q(x-a)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m_2} b_i (x-a)^i$$

In the first case we have

$$p(q(x-a))=\sum\limits_{i=n}^{m_1} a_i \left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m_2} b_i (x-2a)^j -a \right )^i$$

In the second we have

$$p(q(x-a))=\sum\limits_{i=n}^{m_1} a_i \left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m_2} b_i (x-a)^j -a \right )^i$$

Is this sort of what the comment is saying? If so, is the next step to somehow conclude that all $(x-a)$ factors have a degree $>n$ in this second expression?

Comment: It's been a Long Time since I taught from Spivak and I do not have access to the book, but it looks to me that the expressions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ should be viewed instead as $p(x-a)$ and $q(x-a)$. (The second amounts to your second interpretation. That is, your second interpretation looks correct, but in addition $p$ is meant to be written solely in terms of $x-a$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many typographical errors in part (c). Looking at the intended application of part (c) and its remark, the most general true statement is:

> If $p$ and $q$ are polynomials and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$ then
> $$p(q(x) +R(x)) = p(q(x)) + \overline R(x)$$
> where $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\overline R(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0.$$
> Also note that if $q$ is a polynomial in $x-a$ and $p$ is a polynomial in $x-b$ with $b=q(a)$, then $p(q)$ is a polynomial in $x-a$. Moreover, if $p$ has only terms of degree $\ge n$, then all terms of $p(q)$ are of degree $\ge n$.

To prove (c), first write the Taylor polynomial for $p$ at $a$:
$$p(t) = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{p^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(t-a)^k$$ Substitute $a=q(x)$ and $t=q(x)+R(x)$:
$$p(q(x)+R(x))=\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{p^{(k)}(q(x))}{k!}(R(x))^k
$$ Subtracting $p(q(x))$ starts the sum at $k=1$:
$$\overline R(x):=p(q(x)+R(x))-p(q(x))=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{p^{(k)}(q(x))}{k!}(R(x))^k
$$
Divide through by $(x-a)^n$:
$$\frac{\overline R(x)}{(x-a)^n}:=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{p^{(k)}(q(x))}{k!}\left[\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^n}\right]^k(x-a)^{n(k-1)}
$$
Now let $x\to a$. The quantity in square brackets tends to zero, while every other factor in the sum tends to a constant (possibly zero).

---

The remark is easily proved: If $p(x)=\sum_{k=n}^N p_k(x-b)^k$ and $q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^Mq_i(x-a)^i$, then
$$
p(q(x)) = \sum_{k=n}^N p_k(q(x)-b)^k.
$$
But $b=q(a)=q_0$ so $$q(x)-b=q(x)-q_0=\sum_{i=1}^Mq_i(x-a)^i$$ is a polynomial in $x-a$ whose terms $(x-a)^i$ all have degree at least $1$. Therefore $p(q(x))$ is a polynomial in $x-a$, all of whose terms have degree at least $n$.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because I was able to reproduce the steps to understand the comment at the end of item $(c)$. However, is there really a typographical error in item $(c)$ itself? Can we not prove the result with the limit as $x\to 0$?

Comment: The correction I've proposed is the most general result. Writing $x\to 0$ instead of $x\to a$ leads to a statement that's true, but not useful unless also $a=0$ (as is the case in part 9(d)). But this leads to the question why we write $(x-a)^n$ instead of just $x^n$. In other words, having $(x-a)^n$ but $x\to0$ is per se not a typographical error but it limits the generality of the result and causes confusion about the purpose of the parameter $a$ in part (c).

Comment: hi, sorry to comment on an old post. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your notation (or language) but, for your very first step, you write the following equivalence: $$p(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{p^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(t-a)^k$$ Why is this correct? Where's the remainder term? Shouldn't the equivalence read:

$$p(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{p^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(t-a)^k+\frac{p^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}(t-a)^{(n+1)}$$ for some $z \in (a,t)$.

What additional assumption are you using to set that remainder term equal to $0$? Are you asserting that $p$ is an $n$-degree polynomial, too? Making its $(n+1)$-th derivative $=0$?

Comment: (Perhaps this is implicit in the argument.....maybe you are just saying 'Let $p$ be an $n$-degree polynomial, and let $q$ be an $m$-degree polynomial. Consider the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial expansion of $p$. Noting that that the remainder term would equal $0$ under these circumstances...)

Comment: @S.C. Good catch, the most general result would have $p$ be a polynomial of degree $N$, and in that case the sum runs from $k=0$ to $k=N$ with no remainder term. I have edited the answer to change the upper limit to $N$.