# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 10c: How to compute the Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{\cos}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

> 10. (c) Find $P_{5,0,\tan}(x)$. Hint: first use Problem $9$(f) and the value of $P_{5,0,\cos}(x)$ to find $P_{5,0,1/\cos}(x)$.

As a note on notation, $P_{5,0,\tan}(x)$ is the fifth order Taylor polynomial at $0$ of $\tan$.

For this question, I am interested in the computation of $P_{n,0,\frac{1}{1-\cos}}(x)$ specifically.

In Problem $9$(f), it was shown that if $g(a)=0$ then

$$P_{n,a,\frac{1}{1-g}}(x)=\left [ \sum_{i=0}^n \left ( P_{n,a,g}(x) \right )^i \right ]_n$$

where $[P]_n$ denotes the truncation of a polynomial $P$ to degree $n$, that is, it is the sum of all terms of $P$ of degree $\leq n$.

The solution manual does the following

$$P_{n,0,\frac{1}{1-\cos}}(x)=\left [ \frac{1}{1-(\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!})} \right ]_5\tag{1}$$

$$=\left [ 1+\left (\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{24}\right ) +\left (\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{24}\right )^2  \right ]_5$$

$$=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}\tag{2}$$

**My question is simply: where does $(1)$ come from?**

I will also add my own two attempts below.

**In my first attempt,** I tried letting $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=\cos{x}$ and using the relationship

$$P_{n,a,f\circ g}(x)=[ P_{n,g(a),f}\circ P_{n,a,g}]_n=[ P_{n,g(a),f}(P_{n,a,g}(x))]_n$$

which was proved in the problem $9$(e) just before.

Then, computing the Taylor polynomial of $f$ we have

$$P_{n,a,f}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{(x-a)^i}{a^{i+1}}$$

And since $a=0$ in this problem, we have $g(a)=g(0)=1$. Thus

$$P_{n,1,f}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (x-1)^i$$

$$P_{n,0,g}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}$$

and

$$P_{n,0,f\circ g}(x)=[ P_{n,1,f}(P_{n,0,g}(x))]_n$$

$$=\left [ \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (-1)^j \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!} \right )^i \right ]_n\tag{3}$$

Thus

$$P_{5,0,f\circ g}(x)=P_{5,0,\frac{1}{\cos}}(x)=\left [ \sum\limits_{i=0}^5 \left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^5 (-1)^j \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!} \right )^i \right ]_5\tag{4}$$

$(2)$ is quite a complicated expression.

**In my second attempt,** I used $\cos{x}=1-g(x)$, so $g(x)=1-\cos{x}$ and

$$P_{2n+1,0,g}(x)=1-\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}$$

$$=1-\left [ 1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}\right ]$$

$$=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}$$

Thus

$$P_{5,0,\frac{1}{\cos}}(x)=P_{5,0,\frac{1}{1-g}}(x)=\left [ \sum\limits_{i=0}^5[P_{5,0,g}(x) ]^i \right ]_5$$

$$=\left [ \sum\limits_{i=0}^5\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^2 (-1)^{j+1} \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!} \right )^i \right ]_5\tag{5}$$

Now, $(4)$ and $(5)$ seem to be different expressions, both involving lots of complicated terms. I asked a question on MaplePrimes about how to truncate polynomials in Maple, but for now I can't tell if they are different, or indeed if one of them is equal to what Spivak has as the correct answer for the Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{\cos}$ that we see in $(2)$.

In addition to my first question, it would be nice to get feedback on these two attempts. It seems at least one of them is incorrect.

Comment: One should take $g(x)=1-\cos x$, then $1/(1-g)=1/\cos$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **My question is simply: where does (1) come from?**

(1) comes from an error in notation. Look back at the problem and you see that it is $P_{5,0,\frac 1{\cos}}$ you need to calculate for the hint, not $P_{5,0,\frac 1{1-\cos}}$. You cannot calculate $P_{5,0,\frac 1{1-\cos}}$ at all, as $\frac 1{1-\cos x}$ is not even defined at $x = 0$, much less differentiable. And the singularity is a pole, not removable. Someone accidently replaced $g$ with $\cos$ in the Taylor polynomial notation, when they meant to replace $\frac 1{1-g}$ with $\frac 1\cos$.

A further issue is that (1) also doesn't quite follow the hint, but instead follows pretty much the same path you did in your first attempt, except they shortcutted a bit, and most importantly instead of writing out frightening summation notations, they substituted in the much less frightening simple expressions those summations represent:
$$P_{5,0,\cos}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^2 (-1)^{j+1} \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}$$

(In writing up your first attempt here, you incorrectly have $5$ as the upper limit of the sum, but in the second attempt, you wrote the correct upper limit of $2$, so I assume the first was a typo.)

So the final formula of your first attempt can be expressed more simply as
$$P_{5,0,\frac1{\cos}}(x) = \left[1 + \left(\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}\right) + \left(\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^2 +\  \dots\right]_5$$

Which is also what they would have gotten by directly applying 9(f) instead of reverting to earlier formulas. The next thing to notice is that the "$+\ \dots$" at the end can be dropped (which is why I didn't bother to write it out). Any power $\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^i$ for $i>2$ will, when multiplied out, consist only of terms of degree $6$ or greater, and we are throwing out anything with a degree greater than $5$. Thus your "quite a complicated expression" actually isn't that complicated after all. Even the $\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^2$ only contributes $\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}\right)^2$ to the Taylor polynomial, the other terms being of too high degree. So
$$P_{5,0,\frac1{\cos}}(x) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^4}{2!^2} = 1 + \frac 12 x^2 +\frac 5{24}x^4$$

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that you can use a modified version of $9\text{f}$ to solve this problem. Specifically, rather than proving that :

> If $g(a)=0$, $P_{n,a,\frac{1}{1-g}}=\left[1+P_{n,a,g}+(P_{n,a,g}^2+\cdots+(P_{n,a,g})^n) \right]_n$...(which is the original version of $9\text{f}$)

you can just as well prove that:

> If $g(a)=1$: $P_{n,a,\frac{1}{g}}=[1-\left(P_{n,a,g}-1\right)^1+(P_{n,a,g}-1)^2-\cdots+(-1)^k(P_{n,a,g}-1)^k+\cdots+(-1)^n(P_{n,a,g}-1)^n]$

To prove this, recall that the $\frac{1}{g}$ function is equivalently described as the composition of $\frac{1}{I} \circ g$ where $I$ is the identity function. It will be convenient to view $\frac{1}{I}$ itself as a composition of two functions: $(\cdot)^{-1} \circ I$. Using the chain rule and induction, you should be able to determine that $[(\cdot)^{-1}\circ I]^{(k)}=(-1)^k \times k! \times\left[(-1)^{k+1}\circ I\right]$. Now, plugging an arbitrary $z$ into this function gives us:

\begin{align}[(\cdot)^{-1}\circ I]^{(k)}(z)&=(-1)^k \times k! \times\left[(-1)^{k+1}\circ I\right](z)\\&=\frac{(-1)^k\times k!}{z^{k+1}}\end{align}

From the results of $9\text{e}$ (which are considerably better argued on this post here: [Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 9d: Understanding Solution Manual Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527163/spivak-ch-20-problem-9d-understanding-solution-manual-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1)), we know that:

$$P_{n,a,\frac{1}{g(x)}}=P_{n,a,\left[\frac{1}{I}\circ g\right](x)}=\left[P_{n,g(a),\frac{1}{x}}\circ P_{n,a,g(x)}\right]_n$$

Referring to the terms within the square brackets, we can expand the composition as follows:

\begin{align} &=\frac{(-1)^0\times0!\frac{1}{g(a)}}{0!}(P_{n,a,g(x)}-g(a))^0+\frac{(-1)^1\times 1!\frac{1}{g(a)^2}}{1!}(P_{n,a,g(x)}-g(a))^1+\frac{(-1)^2\times2!\frac{1}{g(a)^3}}{2!}(P_{n,a,g(x)}-g(a))^2+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n\times n!\frac{1}{g(a)^{n+1}}}{n!}(P_{n,a,g(x)}-g(a))^n\end{align}

If we cancel out some of the terms and plug in $g(a)=1$, the above expression becomes:

\begin{align}1-\left(P_{n,a,g(x)}-1\right)+\left(P_{n,a,g(x)}-1\right)^2+\cdots+\left(P_{n,a,g(x)}-1\right)^n \quad (\dagger)\end{align}

So why is this useful for our problem of $g(x)=\cos(x)$? Well, we are interested in finding $P_{5,0,\tan(x)}$. Given that $\tan(x)=\sin \times\frac{1}{\cos}$, we necessarily need to evaluate the Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{\cos}$ at $a=0$. By the composition rules we proved earlier in Problem 9, this means we need to find the Taylor polynomial of $\cos$ centered at $a=0$.

Let us now plug in some values from above to show how $(\dagger)$ collapses to a more preferable form:

\begin{align}P_{n,0,\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}=\left[1-\left(P_{n,0,\cos(x)}-1\right)+\left(P_{n,0,\cos(x)}-1\right)^2+\cdots+\left(P_{n,0,\cos(x)}-1\right)^n\right]_n \quad (*)\end{align}

But $P_{n,0,\cos(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots\pm(1)\frac{x^n}{n!}$ where the $\pm$ depends on the value of $n$, and, therefore, in the context of $(*)$, the leading $1$ of $P_{n,0,\cos(x)}$ will be eliminated.

Returning to the evaluation of Spivak's $P_{5,0\tan(x)}$...and thus the evaluation of $P_{5,0,\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}$, we arrive at the solution:

\begin{align}P_{5,0,\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}&=\left[1-\left[-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right]^1+\left[-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right]^2\right]_5\\&=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^4}{2!2!}\\&=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}-2\frac{x^4}{2!4!}+4\times 3\frac{x^4}{4!2!}\\&=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+5\frac{x^4}{4!}\end{align}